# Hiding and printing plots in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, editing

I have a script in matlab that prints the n-derivatives of a function f(x). The purpose of the graph is to "guess" graphically the multiplicity of a root of the function that is unknown. Obviously if I know the root, I can simply evaluate the derivative at that point, but in my case, the functions I will be inputting won't have an easy to find root, so I have to use numerical methods to find them, and figuring out the multiplicity is needed. So far so good, everything in my code works as intended, and the graph has the original function with all it's n derivatives plotted on it as well. Now in my case, the graph becomes kind of cluttered. Is there a way to disable/enable a specific graph once it's plotted? For instance, say I have a plot of f(x), f'(x) and f''(x), is it possible to disable the plot "f''(x)"  so only f(x) and f'(x) remain on the plot (without adding or modifying my code) through the plot interface? Then later on if I wanted to re-enable f''(x) and remove f'(c) through once again the plot interface. I've looked through the different menus but couldn't find a way to remove a specific plot (or to add one later on). I just want to hide it so I can read the graph in places where different derivatives intersect or overlap, but I don't want the plots to be on different subplots either. Thanks! I would post a picture but unfortunately I don't have the reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'Visible' property:

```
x=-14:15;
h_ax=axes();
hold(h_ax,'on');
h_line=cell([3 1]);
for i=1:3
  y=rand(30,1);
  h_line{i}=plot(h_ax,x,y);
end
legend(h_ax,{'f','f^\prime','f^{\prime\prime}'});

set(h_line{2},'Visible','off');
```

The legend indicates that the disabled plot exists, but is hidden. To make the plot visible again at a later time, use: `set(h_line{2},'Visible','on');`

Comment: Is there no way to do this from the graph? Do I need to put it in my code? My issue is that I have a script that does everything automatically, all I have to do is input and the script takes care of the plot. If I were to add the code, I'd have to modify the script by adding the visible thing and run it from scratch every time to enable/disable a plot. I was looking for something more along the line of geogebra, where I can check/uncheck a function to add / remove the plot.

Comment: Oh you want a GUI solution? More specifically, one that does not require writing custom callback functions and such? You can just click View -> Plot Browser. You will be presented with a list of elements that can be turned on/off.

Comment: Hi yes! Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, but for some reason I can't uncheck the plots. Do I have to add something in my code to enable it?

Comment: Is your program still running when you try to click the checkboxes? MATLAB often becomes unresponsive (or partially responsive) while it's busy running something, so maybe you need to wait for your program to complete first.

Comment: Hi, so the program promtps the user for a function and then prompts the user for how many derivatives it wishes to plot. Once the user enters the function and amount of derivatives, the script plots all the relevant functions and then another prompt shows up, so the script is technically running, but it's not doing any intensive computation, it's just waiting for a third prompt.